# ModuleNotFoundError - Module found in PyCharm intellisense but not when executing program

Tags: python, pycharm, python-import, importerror

Using PyCharm, I have a project for an SMTP parser with the following structure:

```
- SMTP
  - Classes
    - Models
    - Transformers
  - Tests
```

In `Tests` I reference classes from `SMTP.Classes.Transformers` like this:

`from SMTP.Classes.Transformers.myclass import MyClass`

This works and my unit tests are run properly.

However, I now added a proxy file `myProxy.py`:

```
- SMTP
  - Classes
    - Models
    - Transformers
  - Tests 
  - myProxy.py
```

In `myProxy.py` I try to import my classes, just like above:

`from SMTP.Classes.Transformers.myclass import MyClass`

When I type `from S`, PyCharm actually suggests `SMTP` and when I write it out, it shows no errors. I can even start `myProxy` within PyCharm, using the "run" button.

However, when I try to run `myProxy.py` from console, I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'SMTP'`

When I remove the `SMTP` part from every affected file, then I can run this from console. And it even runs on PyCharm. However, PyCharm does underline my imports as false for some reason.

What exactly is the error here, and how do I solve it so that I don't have errors in PyCharm and can run my program on both PyCharm and console?

Comment: are you using a virtual env to which you are isntalling the modules to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attempt to omit the `SMTP` and instead simply mark `Classes` as Sources Root in PyCharm, by going: right-click on `Classes` directory > Mark Directory as > Sources Root.

Comment: I found that out literally 10 seconds after posting this question, but you were just a bit quicker than myself in answering my question.
One can also do this via File->Settings->Project: [name]->Project Structure.